# How to ignore Python warnings for complex numbers

Tags: python, list, numpy, complex-numbers

I have a list that I need to include both real values and complex values. However, when I don't initialize the array using numpy.zeros(dtype=complex), I get the following error:

```
n[2] = 3.7095 + 0.007j
```

> TypeError: can't convert complex to float

However, when I do set the dtype to complex, I get the following warning when I use a real number (which doesn't break my code, but it causes a ton of unnecessary red warning messages that clutter my console:

> ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary
>   part

How can I disable the warning message, or set it up another way so the values can be imaginary or complex?

Comment: Using real numbers with an array of complex dtype should not give you a ComplexWarning. If you are getting such a warning, you have some other bug you're not showing us.

Comment: That warning is from doing something like: `numpy.array([2+3j]).astype(numpy.int)`. I think you've got your two cases mixed up. Why not just use complex numbers for everything, `2+0j` is just as "real" as `2`. If you need just the real part for something, just do `numpy.array([2+3j]).real`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this to ignore warning messages:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

Documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html

I have included the link of the documentation as there are also more "soft" methods to deal with warning, such as printing only the first occurrence of the warning ('once').
It is also possible to filter only certain classes of warnings (ComplexWarning) in your case.

Comment: Sure, but keep in mind that the warning should also serve to tell you that you are not handling your data safely/efficiently, so silencing the warnings instead of fixing the code is not a great idea.